# Eigenvalues and classification of critical points

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, linear-algebra, eigenvalues, vector-calculus

I started with a function (x,y) and tried to write the code to work out the eigenvalues and classify the critical points.

The output it all good up until I try to use Which[] to classify the critical points.

Anybody know where I'm going wrong?

The desired output for classification should be "Minimum" because the eigenvalues (6,2) are both positive:

```
(* Function *)
A[x_, y_] := 2 x*y + 2*(1/(x*y))*x + 2 y*(1/(x*y))

(*Gradient of function*)
GradA = Grad[A[x, y], {x, y}]
```

> {2 y-2/x^2,2 x-2/y^2}

```
(*Find critical points of function*)
criticalPoints = Solve[Grad[A[x, y], {x, y}] == {0, 0}, {x, y}, Reals]
```

> {{x->1,y->1}}

```
(* Hessian Matrix *)
hessianMatrix = D[Grad[A[x, y], {x, y}], {{x, y}}] /. criticalPoints
```

> ({4,2} {2,4})

```
(* Eigenvalues of Hessian Matrix *)
eigenvalues = Eigenvalues /@ hessianMatrix
```

> (6 2)

```
Print["Eigenvalues:", eigenvalues]
```

> Eigenvalues:(6 2)

```
(* Classifying critical points [Max,Min,Saddle] *)
classification = Which[
       AllTrue[eigenvalues, # > 0 &], "Minimum", 
       AllTrue[eigenvalues, # < 0 &], "Maximum", True, "Saddle Point"]

Print["Classification:", classification]
```

> Classification:Which[{6,2}>0,Minimum,AllTrue[eigenvalues,#1<0&],Maximum,True,Saddle Point]

However, The desired output for classification should be "Minimum" because the eigenvalues (6,2) are both positive.

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. `classification = 
 Which[AllTrue[eigenvalues, First@# > 0 &], "Minimum", 
  AllTrue[eigenvalues, First@# < 0 &], "Maximum", True, 
  "Saddle Point"]`

Comment: Thank you my kind sir/madam!

Comment: Instead of explicitly computing the eigenvalues, consider using functions like `PositiveDefiniteMatrixQ[]` instead.

Answer (score 3):

```
Clear[A]
A[x_, y_] := 2 x*y + 2*(1/(x*y))*x + 2 y*(1/(x*y))

criticalPoints = Solve[D[A[x, y], {{x, y}}] == 0, {x, y}, Reals]
(* Out: {{x -> 1, y -> 1}} *)

hessian = D[A[x, y], {{x, y}, 2}] /. criticalPoints
(* Out: {{{4, 2}, {2, 4}}} *)

eigenvalues = Eigenvalues /@ hessian
(* Out: {{6, 2}} *)

classifier = Which[
    AllTrue[#, # > 0 &], "Minimum",
    AllTrue[#, # < 0 &], "Minimum",
    True, "Saddle point"
    ] &;

classifier /@ eigenvalues
(* "Minimum" *)
```

Answer (score 2):

First note, the Hessian can be written by:

```
D[Grad[A[x, y], {x, y}], {{x, 2}, {y, 2}}]
```

"Which" is not the cause of your problem, you have syntax errors. After correction of thouse errors:

```
Clear["Global`*"]
A[x_, y_] := 2 x*y + 2*(1/(x*y))*x + 2 y*(1/(x*y));
criticalPoints = {x, y} /. 
  Solve[Grad[A[x, y], {x, y}] == {0, 0}, {x, y}, Reals][[1]]
hessianMatrix = 
 D[A[x, y], {{x, y}, 2}] /. Thread[{x, y} -> criticalPoints]
eigenvalues = Eigenvalues[hessianMatrix]
classification = 
 Which[AllTrue[eigenvalues, # > 0 &], "Minimum", 
  AllTrue[eigenvalues, # < 0 &], "Maximum", True, "Saddle Point"]
```

Comment: The Hessian can also be written as `D[A[x, y], {{x, y},2}]`